# I am trying to return the guesses where Bulls represents correct number and index, and Cows shows correct number only

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

The question I am trying to solve is:

You are playing the following Bulls and Cows game with your friend: You write down a number and ask your friend to guess what the number is. Each time your friend makes a guess, you provide a hint that indicates how many digits in said guess match your secret number exactly in both digit and position (called "bulls") and how many digits match the secret number but locate in the wrong position (called "cows"). Your friend will use successive guesses and hints to eventually derive the secret number.

Write a function to return a hint according to the secret number and friend's guess, use A to indicate the bulls and B to indicate the cows.

Please note that both secret number and friend's guess may contain duplicate digits.

Here are examples of what should happen for the function I am writing:

Example 1:
Input: secret = "1807", guess = "7810"
Output: "1A3B"
Explanation: 1 bull and 3 cows. The bull is 8, the cows are 0, 1 and 7.

Example 2:
Input: secret = "1123", guess = "0111"
Output: "1A1B"
Explanation: The 1st 1 in friend's guess is a bull, the 2nd or 3rd 1 is a cow.

The code I've written doesn't work at the third for loop.  It doesn't seem to iterate over all the members of the array, and I can't figure out why.

```
const getHint = (secret, guess) => {
    s = secret.split('')
    g = guess.split('')
    const secretHash = {}
    const guessHash = {}
    let bulls = 0
    let cows = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < secret.length; i++) {
        secretHash[i] = s[i]
        guessHash[i] = g[i]
    }

    for (let key in secretHash) {
        if (secretHash[key] === guessHash[key]) {
            bulls++
            delete secretHash[key]
            delete guessHash[key]
        }
    }
    let values = Object.values(secretHash)
    //let guessVal = Array.from(new Set(Object.values(guessHash))) //works for the first two but not the last
    let guessVal = Object.values(guessHash) //amended, but now breaks the code for the previous two examples
    console.log(values, 'i am the values')
    console.log(guessVal, 'i am the guessVal')

    //amended but won't work for the last example which includes duplicates
    for (let key of guessVal) {
        console.log(key);
        if (values.includes(key)) {
            delete values[key]
            delete guessVal[key]
            cows++
        }
    }
    return `${bulls}A${cows}B`
}

console.log(getHint('1807', '7810')) //'1A3B'
console.log(getHint('1123', '0111')) //'1A1B'
console.log(getHint('1122', '2211')) //'0A4B'
```

The logic seems to be right, but it's not iterating the way I expect it to.  Any thoughts or suggestions as to why it's not working?

Comment: plz edit ur question by adding how u are calculating cows and bulls.

Comment: *"I am trying to write a function for Bulls vs Cows"* isn't a good title for a question, nor does it relate to any programming concept. Your question title should be a short summary of the question. Are you really asking about bulls and cows here?

Comment: `if (values.indexOf(key)) {` will skip the 0 case (`key` was first element of `values`). `indexOf()` returns -1, not 0, for the "not found" case - check for that explicitly.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: I assume that it is a game that is common in some part of the world (like Tic-Tac-Toe for example), but I never heard from it.

Comment: Your updated question title really is not any better than the first one. You aren't asking a question. You're stating what you are trying to do, but not even in a programming context. Based on reading into your question, you are having a problem with a loop iteration. That should be what your title is about (i.e. "Loop doesn't iterate over all members of an array").

Answer (score 0):

I solved it the following way, not sure if there's any optimizations that can be suggested.  I could not find a way to optimize further than this.

```
const getHint = (secret, guess) => {
    s = secret.split('')
    g = guess.split('')
    const secretHash = {}
    const guessHash = {}
    let bulls = 0
    let cows = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < secret.length; i++) {
        secretHash[i] = s[i]
        guessHash[i] = g[i]
    }

    for (let key in secretHash) {
        if (secretHash[key] === guessHash[key]) {
            bulls++
            delete secretHash[key]
            delete guessHash[key]
        }
    }

    let values = Object.values(secretHash)
    let guessVal = Object.values(guessHash)
    let findIndex


    for (let i = 0; i < guessVal.length; i++) {
        if (values.includes(guessVal[i])) {
            findIndex = values.findIndex(val => val === guessVal[i])
            values[findIndex] = -1
            guessVal[i] = -1
            cows++
        }
    }
    return `${bulls}A${cows}B`
}
```